# How to instantiate a generic class that makes use of a generic that extends a nested class?

Tags: java, generics, nodes, instance

Right now, I have a binary tree class that I imported. First, I cannot create an instance of it because the constructor asks to pass a parameter in `Node`. Problem is, `Node` extends `BTNode<Node>` so I simply cannot just put an `Integer` into the generic as I did below. The binary tree class is as so:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

/**
* An implementation of binary trees
* @author morin
*
* @param <Node>
*/

public class BinaryTree<Node extends BinaryTree.BTNode<Node>> {

    public static class BTNode<Node extends BTNode<Node>> {
        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public Node parent; 
    }

    protected Node sampleNode;  

    protected Node r;

    public BinaryTree(Node sampleNode) {
        this.sampleNode = sampleNode;
    }

    //Some methods

}
```

Originally, I tried invoking the class as so:

```
BinaryTree<Integer> myTree=new BinaryTree<Integer>();
```

But the valid way is instead of `Integer`, putting a reference to `BTNode`. But the dilemma is that in order to reference `BTNode` which is in `BinaryTree` I believe I need to instantiate `BinaryTree` in the first place. What is the right way in which I can access `BTNode` so that I can pass it into the generic `BinaryTree<Node>` class?

Comment: What library did you import to get the binary tree?

Comment: @NAMS I did not import any library myself. Binary Tree is its own class. The only imports were the ones declared in the class import java.util.LinkedList; and import java.util.Queue;

Comment: You're confusing Node with an actual class name. It's not. Usually, generic types use a single uppercase letter. So the above declaration is strictly equivalent to `BinaryTree<T extends BinaryTree.BTNode<T>>`. And, since T must extend BinaryTree.BTNode, Integer clearly doesn't qualify.

Comment: The first sentence of your question is "Right now, I have a binary tree class that I imported."

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, that makes sense. The key for me now is to find a way to access `Node` in a way that qualifies as a valid `Node`